# How to prove these 6 first ODES have no closed-form solution? (About the three-body problems)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dq_{r} }{dq_{1} } =\frac{\partial K}{\partial p_{r} } ,\frac{dp_{r} }{dq_{1} } =\frac{\partial K}{\partial q_{r} }\quad \quad r=(2,3,4)$

where:

$\frac{K^{2}}{2 \mu _1}  = h+\frac{m_1 m_3}{\sqrt{-\frac{2 m_2 q_2 q_1 \left(\cos q_3 \cos q_4-\frac{\left(k^2-p_3^2-p_4^2\right) \sin q_3 \sin q_4}{2 p_3 p_4}\right)}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{m_2^2 q_1^2}{\left(m_1+m_2\right){}^2}+q_2^2}}+\frac{m_2 m_3}{\sqrt{\frac{2 m_1 q_2 q_1 \left(\cos q_3 \cos q_4-\frac{\left(k^2-p_3^2-p_4^2\right) \sin q_3 \sin q_4}{2 p_3 p_4}\right)}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{m_1^2 q_1^2}{\left(m_1+m_2\right){}^2}+q_2^2}}+\frac{m_1 m_2}{q_1}-\frac{p_2^2}{2 \mu _2}-\frac{p_3^2}{2 \mu _1 q_1^2}-\frac{p_4^2}{2 \mu _2 q_2^2}\quad \quad$$(\mu_1,\mu_2,h,m_1,m_2,m_3$ are all constants)

(1). the three-body's motion equations can be written in Hamiltonian form as a set of 18 first order differential equations.

(2). besides the 10 integrals (the 6 integrals of the motion of the center of mass, the 3 integrals of angular momentum and the integral of energy), Poincaré and Bruns proved there are no others.

(3). together with the “elimination of the time” and the “elimination of the nodes” (or SO2 symmetry), the original 18 equations can be reduced to above 6. And it can't be reduced further.

(4). because of (3), the problem has no closed form solution which means it can't be expressed analytically in terms of a finite number of certain "well-known" functions. (This is what we always say the three-body problem has no "solution". But, Sundman had proved there exist a series of power expansion solutions to the three-body problem.)

I find these equations in a book where there were originally eight of them. And it tells me an easy way to reduce to 6. There are serval chapters about how they proved (2), but nothing about (4). My question is how to prove (4). And is this proved only this method (reduced to 6 by integrals) doesn't have closed form solution, or all methods don't have?

Comment: That's a bit too much of a request, to expect us, based on a six-part question, to prove them for you??

Comment: @amWhy the problem is when they reduced to 6, there is no closed form solution. So, if we know the 6 equations, maybe it will help to understand why.

Comment: "But, Sundman had proved there exist a series of power expansion solutions to the three-body problem."  Can you cite the source of your question?

Comment: @amWhy I read his original [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-36/issue-none/M%c3%a9moire-sur-le-probl%c3%a8me-des-trois-corps/10.1007/BF02422379.full).He proved this by Cauchy's theorem.The theorem is on page 113. He proved the original 18 equations had series of power expansion solutions by using some [transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem).You can also see them on the last 5 page of the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Alnseven. It would help if you included that link in your question. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

A nice historical overview of the three-body problem is given in [1] on pp. 726. Reading quickly it does not seem the case that the non-existence of a general closed form solution is mathematically established. It is rather the case that

> despite the discovery of the particular solutions and a century of unrelenting work on the problem, the mathematicians of the nineteenth century were unable to find a general solution. Indeed, the problem was considered so hard that in 1890 Poincare was led to declare that he thought it impossible without the discovery of some significant new mathematics.

T. Gowers, J. Barrow-Green, I. Leader (eds.) *The Princeton Companion to Mathematics*. 2008.

Comment: I also doubt if there is a proof.But I find this"...This means that in general there is no closed form solution ..."in [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086009001360?via%3Dihub)

Comment: You could be more specific when you quote from a 40 page paper. Which page? Having said that: I doubt that June Barrow-Green states here anything different than what she wrote above. The non-existence result that you want to proove is too grand to be buried in side remarks. Imho this is millenium price/fields medal stuff.

Comment: Sorry about the page. It's on page 13, but you can directly search "This means that in general" by Ctrl+F after you click the link. And another one also said about [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-rigorous-proof-that-the-three-body-problem-has-no-analytical-solution/answer/Paul-Camp-3).And someone [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815490/there-is-no-closed-form-solution-of-the-three-body-problem-is-this-just-a-fol) tried to find a proof, something about differential Galois group which I don't know. But as you said, it shouldn't be buried in side remarks.